# Проблема с составлением ListView из CustomView

Tags: java, android, customview

есть свой CustomView class

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener
```

В него входит элемент класса Note

```
public class Note {
  private String text;
  private int image;
  private boolean click;
  private boolean isdone;
....
```

Note.click отвечает за "нажато/не нажато", Note.isdone - в зависимости от значения меняется фон записи. Ниже приведён метод Onclick() , в котором done, forward,edit,detail - четыре ImageButton, выскакивающие при нажатии, а edit меняет фон. collapse и expand - анимация появления и исчезания кнопок.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!note.getClick()) {

        expand();
        note.setClick(true);
    } else {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.done:
                Log.i("Sometag", "Done pressed");

                break;
            case R.id.forward:
                Log.i("Sometag", "Forward pressed");

                break;
            case R.id.edit:
                Log.i("Sometag", "Edit pressed");
                if (note.getIsdone()) setIsDone(false);
                else setIsDone(true);
                break;
            case R.id.detail:
                Log.i("Sometag", "Detail pressed");

                break;

            default:
                collapse();
                note.setClick(false);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Всё работало прекрасно, пока не дошло дело до списка.
Сделал CustomAdapter, в файле itemoflist.xml только CustomView. showNote просто присваивает из элемента items в CustomView.

```
public class CustomViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Note[] items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomViewAdapter(Context context,Note[] elements){
    this.items=elements;
    this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     CustomView view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = (CustomView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemoflist, null);

    } else {
        view = (CustomView) convertView;

    }
     Note item = (Note) getItem(position);
    view.showNote(item);
    return view;
}
```

}

При изменении состоянии элемента списка, изменяется элемент в невидимой его части. Состояние элементов после нажатия кнопки "Home" не сохраняется, хотя у самого CustomView есть методы onSaveInstanceState() и onRestoreInstanceState.

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle state = new Bundle();

    state.putParcelable(SuperState, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    state.putBoolean(ATTR_VISIBLE,note.getClick());
    state.putBoolean(ATTR_ISDONE,note.getIsdone());

    return state;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable ss) {
    Bundle state = (Bundle) ss;

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.getParcelable(SuperState));
    setVisibility(state.getBoolean(ATTR_VISIBLE));
    setIsDone(state.getBoolean(ATTR_ISDONE));
}
```

MainActivity наследуется от ListActivity, и кроме onCreate() там ничего нет.